# Problem Using Back4App/Parse with React Native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, parsing, expo, back4app

I'm trying out Back4App with React Native Expo and I keep getting a TypeError associated with the Parse.initialize statement. If I comment this statement, the app loads well in the simulator, but once the statement is uncommented, the error is thrown.

" ERROR  TypeError: attempted to use private field on non-instance, js engine: hermes "

My App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Parse from 'parse/react-native.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx");



export default function App() {
  const [todoTitle, setTodoTitle] = useState("");
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>My Todo List</Text>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>List of activities I need to accomplish</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <TextInput placeholder="Add a new todo" onChangeText={setTodoTitle} style={styles.input} />
          <Button title="Add" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: StatusBar.height
  },
  header: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 15,
  },
  headerText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 30,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  descriptionText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  formContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    padding: 20,
  },
  formText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "lightblue",
  }
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I tried to redo the app in snack.expo.dev but kept getting the error that "the module parse/react-native.js cannot be resolved". Just wanted to see if my dev setup was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Expo sdk v50, and I have solved by the following solution.

1. As for your_project_folder/node_mosules/parse/lib/react-native/EventEmitter.js, replace all codes with the followings(same code as parse/lib/node/EventEmitter.js)

-before:

```
var EventEmitter;
try {
  EventEmitter = require('react- 
  native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter');
  if (EventEmitter.default) {
    EventEmitter = EventEmitter.default;
  }
  EventEmitter.prototype.on = EventEmitter.prototype.addListener;
} catch (_) {}
module.exports = EventEmitter;
```

-after:

```
module.exports = require('events').EventEmitter;
var EventEmitter;
```

2. npm install(or yarn add) events
   This "events" module is for Node.js, so is not pre-installed in react-native, but actually run on react-native.
3. npx expo start -c

I hope this will be working for you and other Expo users.

Comment: Thanks Ichiro, I'll give this a try and report on the results

Comment: Now I'm getting this message:

 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Is this related to the first error in some way, or its a totally different issue?

Comment: I could run your code with no such errors on my dev environment. I don't know your dev environment, so ckeck your dev environment (e.g. each module version including expo SDK, app.json, package.json, and so on).

Comment: Following commands may be helpful.
  npx expo install —fix,  
npx expo-doctor

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade `Parse` version to `4.2.0` works for me. Seems like this [new feature](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/pull/1999) in version `^4.3.0` and above does not work with `Expo EventEmitter`.